# Salesforce CPQ remove Search Products

Tags: cpq

Is it possible to Remove the Search Products from the CPQ screen so that the users must use guided selling?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It possible to hide it through creation of VF custom controller extension. Instead of hiding it, I would rather go something easier first like predefined Search Filters to shorten the amount of product to desired ones

Comment: when you said visualforce custom controller extension are you speak of creating a visual force page in place of the cpq screen if so I might as well just write cpq code myself.

I did see that you could create filters, not sure if I can so that or not.